# How to replace function with mock object for unittesting in Python

Tags: python, fabric

How do you replace all references to a function with a mock object in Python?

I'm trying to write some unittests for a Fabric script. Specifically, I want to replace `fabric.api.run` with a mock version that logs the command instead of executing. However, I want to do this in a way so I don't have to rewrite all code that references fabric.

I've tried doing:

```
import fabric.api
_run = fabric.api.run
fabric.api.run = my_mock_run_function
```

but since I can't guarantee this will run before any other modules import fabric.api, a lot of code is still using the real `run` function.

Answer (score 1):

If your code uses:

```
from fabric.api import run
```

you will have to patch the local reference your module has of the run function:

```
@patch('yourmodule.run')
def test_method(self, run):
    pass
```

If your code uses:

```
import fabric.api
...
api.run(...)
```

you will be able to patch the original copy:

```
@patch('fabric.api.run')
def test_method(self, run):
    pass
```

See [this nice explanation](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/).

Answer (score 0):

use [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)

```
import fabric.api
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('fabric.api.run')
    def test_test(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Comment: Note that `mock` is a [third-party module](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) prior to Python 3.3. The OP would probably also want `new=my_mock_run_function` as a keyword argument to `patch` given the sample code he provided.

Comment: I was able to patch `fabric.api` using your solution, but the native `fabric.api.run` function is still called and tries to connect via ssh in the middle of the test. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I have the same problem with `fabric.api.local`, this solution does not work.